# XML: Unhandled rejection Error: Root element needs a name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I want to write create XML code in my nodejs project. I am using below code do the same.
but I got an error: **Unhandled rejection Error: Root element needs a name.**

```
renew.createXML = function () {

    var builder = require('xmlbuilder');
    var doc = builder.create();

    doc.begin('root')
        .ele('xmlbuilder')
        .att('for', 'node-js')
        .ele('repo')
        .att('type', 'git')
        .txt('git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git')
        .up()
        .up()
        .ele('test')
        .txt('complete');

    console.log(doc.toString({ pretty: true }));
}
```

**Can anybody suggest me what I am doing wrong in above code ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the name of the root as the parameter to `create`:

```
builder.create('root');
```

See [the wiki](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki) for details and alternatives.